# Use 0755 as base-8 number

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
function myChmod($path, $permission, $log)
{
    //this is to overcome umask limitations that mkdir adheres to
    $result = chmod($path, octdec($permission));
    if(!$result) {
        $log->log("Error failed to chmod '$path' to '$permission'. Exiting.");
        throw new Exception("Error failed to chmod '$path' to '$permission'. Exiting.");
    }
    return $result;
}

$trml2pdfPath = $c->install_path.'assets/trml2pdf/trml2pdf/trml2pdf.py';
myChmod($trml2pdfPath, 0755, $log);
```

How do I prevent PHP from changing this base-8 number `0755` to base-10 number `493`? I wanna use the chmod function in PHP, but it just keeps changing it to `493`.

Comment: What's wrong with using `0755`? It should work fine with `chmod($path, $permission)` without that `octdec()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's [chmod()](http://docs.php.net/chmod) function takes an integer as second parameter. It does not matter whether you pass octal(0755) or dec(493), it's the same number.

---

`myChmod($trml2pdfPath, 0755, $log);`
the 0755 here is a [number literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29). PHP interprets it as the number oct(755)=dec(493), meaning: you don't need any conversion function in `myChmod()`.

```
$result = chmod($path, $permission);
```

Comment: Updated my question with my function code. Mind to revise your answer?

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.php.net/chmod

> Note that mode is not automatically assumed to be an octal value, so
>   strings (such as "g+w") will not work properly. To ensure the expected
>   operation, you need to prefix mode with a zero (0):

See this example code in php documentation:

```
<?php
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 755);   // decimal; probably incorrect
chmod("/somedir/somefile", "u+rwx,go+rx"); // string; incorrect
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);  // octal; correct value of mode
?>
```

So I guess you need not use base_convert, instead you can directly use the octal number.

This should work for you:

```
$result = chmod($path, str_pad($permission, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

Comment: @Volkerk is correct. you can just use chmod($path, $permission). no need to use str_pad.

Answer (score 0):

have a little trick, change :

```
$result = chmod( $path, octdec( $permission ) );
```

to :

```
$result = chmod( $path, ( ( "0" . octdec( $permission ) ) * 1 ) );
```

hope this help.